# How can I drain water from a bucket into my kitchen sink without lifting it?

Tags: water, drain, pump, washer

I have a portable washer from which I drain water (from its hose) into a bucket and then must lift the bucket (from off the floor) to pour the water into kitchen sink. This bucket-lifting is getting too hard for me. Is there a pump out there to pump water from a 5-gallon bucket into a kitchen sink?

Comment: Electric or manual

Comment: Does the washer have a pump, or does it drain by gravity? If the washer has a pump, is it not able to lift the water high enough to the sink itself?

Comment: Agree with @spuck -- if the washer is a modern one it probably has a drain pump. Just wheel the washer over to the sink (which you probably need to do anyway to supply it with water) and hook the end of the drain hose over the sink edge. Of course if this is an old bucket-and-rollers machine, there isn't a pump built in and you should probably get one.

Answer (score 2):

For a similar task I use a "Table Top Fountain" pump. They are submersible and can hoist the water for that distance. Read the specs, esp. GPH (Gallons per Hour) so you know what the drain rate is for the height required, but generally for a bucket even the smallest pump is fine.

[image]

Attach a hose long enough, drop the pump into the bucket, put the other hose end in the sink, plug it in, and listen to the hum and watch it empty.

It's okay if the pump runs dry for a brief moment at the end of the pumping, and of course the little rest at the bottom can be emptied by lifting and tipping the bucket into the sink as before.

A tiny pump, at 80 GPH, will empty the bucket in under 4 minutes.

But I would get a pump that's a little larger so that it takes less time to lift 36 inches to counter height.

[image]

Calculator: https://www.omnicalculator.com/construction/gallons-per-minute

Answer (score 0):

For no cables or electricity I would use Manual pump.

Ergonomic design, foot operated.

[image: pump]

Just get a 1/2 inch hose at proper length.

Comment: how many foot presses to empty 5 gallons?

Answer (score 0):

If you dump the bucket into the nearest toilet, you won't have to lift it so high.

Comment: But then you have to drag it along, unless you have a bucket with wheels (like a janitor mop bucket).

Comment: The simplest would be to put less water in the bucket.